# Interactive board

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking to do a big "Prezi-like" board where :

- I can zoom in on each of the sub-panels, that is, with "hot spots" that I press and "zoom in" on that sub-panel.
- fields that I can click and fill in things or I can update data based on actions on the board

I guess there's any JS/SVG/HTML5 library to create these kind of "worlds" and have interaction with elements or panels.

Does anybody know the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this library can help you in your needs: https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom

If I remember others I can update the answer to add them.